# Why does this line of code work in python?

Tags: python-2.7

```
number = 2374
number //= 10
# this makes the number 237
```

What is actually happening to make the number's last digit removed? What does //= 10 do?

Comment: `// Floor Division - The division of operands where the result is the quotient in which the digits after the decimal point are removed.` This is being applied and assigned to `number`

Comment: The more long-winded explanation of `//` is in [PEP 238 -- Changing the Division Operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`//` performs a [Floor Division](https://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html).

> Floor Division - The division of operands where the result is the quotient in which the digits after the decimal point are removed.

So in your example, it is taking the number 2374 and dividing it by 10.

This returns 237.4

The 237.4 is then [floored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Examples). Resulting in 237.0, or just 237.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, `//` is used for integer or floored division. Basically the second line is saying the same as `/=` but since its `//=` it will floor the results. So...

`2374 / 10 = 237.4`

...but...

`2374 // 10 = 237`

It floors the results of the division.